# Easy way to save items with params in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have my params array like this:

```
params[:nameCool] = "text1"
params[:nameNotCool] = "text2"
```

I save  my model like

```
o = Option.new
o.nameCool = params[:nameCool]
o.nameNotCool = params[nameNotCool]
```

As you can see the params key has the same name as the new Option method.

Is there any way to do this faster (mapping the attribute with the params key?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `params` Hash is too long, and you want to collect only few of them, you can use [`Hash#slice`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-slice) method.

```
o = Option.new(params.slice(:name_cool, :name_not_cool))
o.save
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
o = Option.new(nameCool: params[:nameCool], nameNotCool: params[:nameNotCool])
```